# My angular 7 apps sitemap.xml is not being picked up by webmaster tools

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, google-search-console

My angular 7 apps sitemap.xml is not being picked up by webmaster tools

**I have this sitemap.xml file (I've hidden real names):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

  <url>
    <loc>https://mywebsite.co.uk/</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-11-28T13:11:30+00:00</lastmod>
  </url>

</urlset>
```

**In webmaster tools I keep getting this error:**

> Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported
>   sitemap format instead.

But my file is a .xml file.
So I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this related to Angular? Is there HTML around the XML?

There should be XML only on https://mywebsite.co.uk/sitemap.xml

Copied Example from one of my sites:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://mywebsite.co.uk/</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Looks like google cant find my sitemap.xml for my angular 7 app

Comment: do you need to create a sitemap.xml route in the angular routing?

Comment: No, you just put a static xml file there. You have to make sure to have it available at example.com/sitemap.xml

If you are using the Angular CLI, look at this tutorial: https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-cli-sitemap-robots-txt/

Comment: thanks for that link - really good - looks like i needed to update my angular json assets array - I will test now

Comment: @AngularM did you manage to sort this issue?  I can see my sitemap.xml when typing it into the URL, but Google still gives me a `couldn't fetch` error.

Comment: @Can Can you please let me know how can I update sitemap.xml at runtime using angular 9?

Answer (score 0):

> Below solution work for angular 2+ version:

> **Step 1:** Create or add sitemap.xml under src/ or src/assets. Add url paths as shown in the example links.

[image]

> **Step 2:** Add the following entry in your angular.json file

[image]

> **Step 3:** Run your angular app and now you can access it via /Sitemap.xml

> **Step 4:** Deploy your changes and access your sitemap.xml at yourdomain/assets/sitemap.xml

*(Note: You can also set your sitemap.xml file into src folder as well)*

1. https://domain_name.com/assets/sitemap.xml
2. http://localhost:4200/assets/sitemap.xml

[image]